# Alternative to '/etc/group' through NSS

Tags: glibc, libc, group, nss, passwd

I would have said that `libc` should have a function (maybe something like `getGroupsByUsername`) that would return a list of all groups a user should be a member of, and that this function would be implemented by NSS. And then, the `files` service from NSS would implement it by looking at the file `/etc/group`.

But as far as I can see, this is not how it works.

There is no function to obtain the list of groups a user should belong. [getgroups(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getgroups.2.html) is not what I'm looking for. That function returns the list of groups the calling process currently belongs to.

So, the questions would be:

- How do I obtain the list of groups a user should belong to? Do I need to parse myself the file `/etc/group`?
- What is the process by which when I login my current process already belongs to all groups specified for my username in `/etc/group`? Is it the `login` program that parses `/etc/group` and then runs [setgroups(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getgroups.2.html)?
- If I want to use an alternative system for managing group membership, could I write an NSS module that would use whatever logic I like?

By the way, I am aware that with functions like [getgrnam(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrnam.3.html) and [getgrent(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrent.3.html) I can obtain the list of all members for each group, but what I need is the opposite, the list of groups a user is member of. I could construct it by using those functions, but it seems there should be an easier way.

Also, there is the function [initgroups(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/initgroups.3.html). I don't know if this function has anything to do with NSS. And it doesn't return the list of groups, just updates the list of groups the calling process belongs to.